# JSP/Java page encoding and database collation issue

Tags: java, jsp, sql-server-2012

I have a web page with text input fields.  If the user pastes text from a Microsoft product (Word, Outlook) the long dashes (m dashes?) and apostrophes (or single quotes) are getting converted to question marks (?) when written to my database table. If they just enter text directly from the keyboard it's fine. How can I prevent or correct this issue?

My JSP page has this above the starting  tag:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
```

My Microsoft SQL 2012 Server default collation is set to:

```
SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

How can I fix this going forward?

Thanks!

Comment: Should I be using UTF-8 instead of ISO-8859-1 in my web application?  Although this seemed to make the problem worse.

Answer (score 2):

This should take you to the right direction

http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html

or

http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=268377